# Laravel Blade function

Tags: function, laravel, laravel-blade

In a view in my Laravel App,I want to display different background in each table cell.

Imagine

```
<td>
  switch($product->number)
      @case('1')
        "red"  
       @break; 
    [...]
  @case('100')
        "green"  
       @break; 
  @endswitch
</td>
```

So, as I have to do it for each cell in a row I was wondering how could I just call a function inside the view that would return the color.

(I know that It would be faster to do it on the client side by js, but I was just wondering).

Comment: "faster" in terms of implementation, probably not in rendering ;) I think you just need to repeat your code for each cell or generate an outer loop. Your code and your explanation at this time are way too scarce to give a possible solution. I recommend you elaborate some more.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a Helper? You can call it in your blade like this:

```
{!!\App\Library\TableHelper::colorText($product->number)!!}
```

And in the Helper that i put under *app/Library*:

```
<?php namespace App\Library;


class TableHelper
{
    public static function colorText($text)
    {
        switch ($text)
        {
            case '1' : $text = '<span color="green"> ' . $text . '</span>'; break;
            //...
        }
        return $text;
    }
    //to only get the color:
    public static function getColor($text)
    {
        switch ($text)
        {
            case '1' : return 'green' ; break;
            //...
            default: return 'white';
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First define a color array and assign to view.

```
$colors = [1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'blue', 4 => 'gray'];
return $this->view('template', ['colors' => $colors]);
```

Then you can get in template.

```
<td>
    {{ array_get($colors, $product->number) }}
</td>
```

I don't know if color is pre-define or not. Maybe this way is what you want.